# ¿Como limito el número de decimales en los índices de un DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Dispongo del siguiente script.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math


data = np.array(
    [[65, 36, 49, 84, 79, 56, 28, 43, 67, 36],
       [43, 78, 37, 40, 68, 72, 55, 62, 22, 82],
       [88, 50, 60, 56, 57, 46, 39, 57, 73, 65],
       [59, 48, 76, 74, 70, 51, 40,  7, 56, 45],
       [35, 62, 52, 63, 32, 80, 64, 53, 74, 34],
       [76, 60, 48, 55, 51, 54, 45, 44, 35, 51],
       [21, 35, 61, 45, 33, 61, 77, 60, 85, 68],
       [45, 53, 34, 67, 42, 69, 52, 68, 52, 47],
       [62, 65, 55, 71, 73, 50, 53, 59, 41, 54],
       [41, 74, 82, 58, 26, 35, 47, 50, 38, 70]]
    )

pd.set_option('precision', 2)
datos = data[:,:].flatten()

# Cálculo del número de intervalos
"""Si la parte entera de k es un número impar, redondeamos a la baja """
k = 1 + 3.322 * math.log10(len(datos))
numero = int(k)
if numero%2 == 0:
    periodos = math.ceil(k)
else:
    periodos = int(k)


inf = datos.min()        # Limite inferior del primer intervalo
dif = datos.max()
"""Sumamos uno al máximo (46) porque en caso de no hacerlo, dado que el intervalo 
es cerrado por su límite superior [..., 46), la observación 46 quedaría fuera del intervalo. """
sup = datos.max() + 1    # Limite superior del último intervalo

intervals = pd.interval_range(
    start=inf,
    end=sup,
    periods=k,
    name="Intervalo",
    closed="left")

df = pd.DataFrame(index=intervals)
df["FreqAbs"] = pd.cut(datos, bins=df.index).value_counts()
# Media de cada intervalo del índice
df["Marca"]  = df.index.mid

df["LimInf"] = df.index.left
df["LimSup"] = df.index.right
df
```

Su ejecución nos devuelve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que los números del índice tengan solamente dos decimales?.
He introducido al principio del script la sentencia

```
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
```

pero no parece servir para solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, notar el problema que la columna `Intervalo` **no posee tipo numérico**, si no que posee tipo `IntervalArray` dado que contiene un intervalo por cada elemento como su indice. El primer paso para poder utilizar funciones numéricas de los `DataFrame` consiste en tener las columnas respectivas con su *dtype* numerico. En este caso deberías separar el intervalo en dos columnas indepedientes de tipo `float32`, por ejemplo, `inicio_intervalo` y `fin_intervalo`.

```
df[['inicio_intervalo','fin_intervalo']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Intervalo.values.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Una vez que tengas las columnas correctamente formateadas, es decir, conteniendo numeros (no listas, como en tu ejemplo). 
Se acotan los decimales mediante la función [`dataframe.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html).

Si quieres redondear todos los numeros del DF haces:

```
df = df.round(2)  # 2 decimales
```

si quieres solo de la columna intervalo.

```
df = df.round({"inicio_intervalo":2, "fin_intervalo":2))
```

Puedes ver más [ejemplos utiles aqui.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-round/)

Comment: Las sentencias "df["LimInf"] = df.index.left" y "df["LimSup"] = df.index.right", ya crean dos columnas independientes con los límites del intervalo. Por otro lado, la sentencia que propones con el mismo objeto, "df[['inicio_intervalo','fin_intervalo']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Intervalo.values.tolist(), index= df.index)", me devuelve el error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Intervalo'"

Comment: El tipo de "Intervalo", es: dtype='interval[float64]'. ¿Donde podré aprender más acerca de este tipo de datos?.

Comment: He intentado resetando el índice, cambiar el tipo de datos de la columna, "df['Intervalo'] = df['Intervalo'].astype('float64')". Me devuelve el error "Cannot cast IntervalArray to dtype float64"

Comment: Ocurre que estas ocupando un tipo intervalo o IntervalArray para indexar el dataframe por lo que la precisión es fundamental para su especificación, a diferencia de una columna normal. Ahora si quieres generar una proyección de estos valores con menor precisión deberás extraer el puntos de inicio y final como columnas independientes, luego serán tipo Float32. Dale una vuelta y me cuentas . Te invito a leer la documentación de los DataFrame, aunque creo que ya la debes haber visto.

Comment: La solución es substituir en la sentencia "intervals =...", sustituir "periods=k," por "freq=freq,"